# Does using the unknown type in a typescript library force all dependents to use typescript version 3.0 or greater?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

I’m wondering if using `unknown` in my exported types in a package distributed via npm forces any code which depends on that library to use typescript 3.0. `unknown` was added in typescript 3.0 (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html). I’m defining and exporting a class which has a method which takes `unknown` as an argument and the `unknown` keyword shows up in the generated `d.ts` file.

Can older typescript compilers handle the `unknown` type in the generated `d.ts` or am I forcing everyone who uses my package to use typescript 3.0 or later? Should I use `any` instead? Is there any way to “shim” this missing type for older typescript versions?

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`typesVersions`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#version-selection-with-typesversions) and then you can at least distinguish between 3.1+ and 3.0-.  For 3.0- you can use `any` or `{} | null | undefined | void` depending on your needs

Comment: might be a big ask but you can also ask sub 3.0 users to use "skipLibCheck": true which disables type-errors in external packages.

Comment: https://github.com/gcanti/unknown-ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older TypeScript compilers cannot handle `unknown`. Here is a shim technique that surprisingly works.

1. Create the following `shim.d.ts` file.
2. Reference that file in your library's main file.

**shim.d.ts**

```
declare global {
    // @ts-ignore
    export type unknown = any;
}

export { }
```

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="shim.d.ts" />

/**
 * This is a tiny demo function that returns `unknown`. Your actual module
 * could include a lot more functionality.
 */
export default (): unknown => {
    return {} as unknown;
};
```

When your library's consumer compiles with an older version of TypeScript, the compiler will create a new type called `unknown` that is an alias for `any`. When your library's consumer compiles with a later version of TypeScript, the compiler will not create a new type, but because of that sneaky `@ts-ignore`, the compiler will also not complain.

[Here is a demo](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-library-unknown-older-targets) of this at work.

As `jcalz` points out in the comments, instead of `any` we could alias `{} | null | undefined | void` instead.

Comment: This is a comprehensive answer! Thanks!